# Microsoft Graph Education API Method not allowed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

When i try to create class at Graph explorer "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/classes" with following request.

```
{
    "description": "Class 9th Frist batch",
    "classCode": "9th-A",
    "displayName": "9th Class",
    "externalId": "11019",
    "externalName": "9th Class",
    "externalSource": "sis",
    "mailNickname": "fineartschool.net"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
        "message": "Method not allowed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7daf0b9c-165a-4c18-a2b9-b90a59d00cc6",
            "date": "2020-05-19T13:26:06"
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to list and create Calender's and events but i am not allowed to create or list classes.
Can anybody guide me what's the issue with my account? Why i am getting above response. How can i use education API?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Graph Explorer uses Delegated scopes but the [Create educationClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationroot-post-classes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint only accepts Application scopes:

- Delegated (work or school account): Not supported.
- Delegated (personal Microsoft account): Not supported.
- Application: `EduRoster.ReadWrite.All`

Since Delegated scopes are not supported, you won't be able to use Graph Explore to create a Class. You will need to use your own code/app to request the `EduRoster.ReadWrite.All` scope and use the [Client Credentials OAuth Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to obtain your token.